# How use entitymaneger .merge(T entity) spring mvc , jpa Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I do not understand how it works please help!
when  i use CrudRepository all is well:

```
    @Transactional
        public Contact save(Contact contact) {
            contactRepository.save(contact);
        }
```

but when  i use my own method:

```
    @Transactional
    public Contact save(Contact contact) {
    if (contact.getid() == null) {
        em.persist(contact);
        return contact;
    } else {
        return em.merge(contact);
    }
}
```

merge does not work... with no exceptions...
 All other CRUD operations are working well..
my root-context.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="appPu"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myProject.myMvcProject"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myProject.myMvcProject"/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.myProject.myMvcProject"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
                  transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>


</beans>
```

Comment: Only adding `@Transactional` isn't going to work. You also need to tell the container you want to use annotation driven annotations. When using java config add `@EnableTransactionManagement` for xml add `<tx:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: what is em in 2nd method?

Comment: @M.Deinum without it the first method wouldnt work either no?

Comment: Well a Spring Data JPA repositories does some other things as well so not necessarily.

Comment: @M.Deinum <tx:annotation-driven />  is in my my root-context.xml..
but I think that you're close to the truth , and the reason it is certainly an error perhaps in the transaction ..

Comment: @Khatarnaak Gunda  em = entitymaneger

Comment: Make sure that only the components in your root-context are transactional. If you use the same component scan for your servlet you will end up with 2 instances 1 with and 1 without transactions.

Comment: @Jonny You don't need to check for the existence of id `if (contact.getid() == null)`. Remove the if loop and persist method and just call `em.merge`, if the entity already exists it updates it else it will create a new record(persist).

Comment: @M.Deinum  Yes you are right! thank you very much to you and to all responded !